# What is the best way to pass a parameter to a running script?

Tags: daemon, parameter

There is a script *(on dash)* that runs at system startup *(as a daemon)*. The script is run under root.

From under a user I create a file with the right parameter, and the script checks once a second if the file exists and reads the parameters.

That is, I pass the parameters to the script (running as root) through the file. Can you give me a better way?

**What is needed:** Execute the script with root privileges by user command (action). Without elevating the user's permissions. Maybe there is an option as with raising the network interface, when running the script from the folder (if-pre-up.d/...). I was looking at udev and plugging in a flash card, but that's not really convenient.

@Marcus Müller For example, there is a file which should become readable to the user for a short time *(root:user 440)*. After that the rights should change back *(root:user 400)*

@Marcus Müller OS Gnu/Linux (Debian). '*this all sounds like you're essentially passing messages between a user and a root daemon.*' - Yes

@Frédéric Loyer I liked the solution with the pipes. The wrong pipe behavior seen by @Marcus Müller does occur, but I need to pass one parameter every 5-30 minutes, so there should be no confusion (b before a). I.e. my script running under root will look something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/dash
mkfifo fifo
while read line <fifo; do
        if [ $line -eq 'arg1' ] ; then
                echo 'Starting...'
        fi
done
```

Right? In terms of safety, does the use of such pipes worsen anything?

Comment: This sounds a bit strange! What's the problem you're solving? I think there might be a choice of elegant solutions to that, and having a script poll some file is not among them, but I don't really know what you need, and I don't want to tell you how to write e.g. a dbus service if that's not really what fulfills the job :)

Comment: um, the file access example you describe is even more strange! Why not simply send the information to the user in question, on demand (or not send it, when it's not permitted)? Can you tell us what **problem** this all addresses?

Comment: to explain: this all sounds like you're essentially passing messages between a user and a root daemon. Which is a perfectly fine thing to do. But the way to do that is via passing messages, not passing files, and there's very classic AND very modern ways of doing that! (and they're quite possibly relatively easy! Just not something you see in every administrative script. By the way, might be worth knowing what your OS is, especially when it comes to permissions. Linux? OpenBSD? Illumos? OS X?)

Comment: so, nice, what does your daemon do, what's the purpose of all this? Please don't make it unnecessarily hard to help you, giving a bit of context makes it easier for us and for you :)

Comment: not related to fifos but: `-eq` is for numeric tests, not string tests.   double-quote $line, and use `=` for the test: `if [ "$line" = 'arg1' ]; echo Starting... ; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the need is just an privilege elevation, `sudo` may be a better than a daemon.

If you really want a background process which wait for a user input, you can create a named pipe with `mkfifo`. Your background process read a line from this named pipe (`read line < the_named_pipe`), and the user has just to write something in it (`echo arg >> the_named_pipe`). Then the background process will do a passive wait instead of an active wait which uses the CPU every second.

Comment: ah, FIFOs are beautiful, but don't forget that they get closed every time the writing process closes them. (and that concurrent write access to a not-yet-opened pipe has ... interesting order semantics)

Comment: The `read a < fifo` reopen the pipe each time if needed. Concurrent accesses issues should effectively be noted. I guess that with 1 line parameters (or one word), this shouldn’t be an issue. But more precision on the parameter format/length could be useful.

Comment: I just tried; basically `mkfifo fifo; (echo a > fifo) &; (echo b > fifo) &; cat fifo` yields `b` followed by `a`, so it's definitely a problem even with single words :)

Comment: Good point. It is not as FIFO I would have thought !  Whether this is an issue depends of the % of time the background process reads the pipe, and if we write oftenly, or once a while (triggering a daily backup for example)… more precision on the need could be useful.

Comment: Yes, I was *exactly* as surprised as you are!

Comment: In fact, I'm still surprised. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685305/linux-named-pipes-not-as-fifo-as-thought

Comment: @MarcusMüller  The Fifo gets closed when the *last* Writer process closes their file descriptor. The classic fix is to have the Reader open a Write fd to the Fifo as well, but not write anything to it. When the Reader wants to terminate cleanly, it closes the write fd. It will then get EOF on its read fd as soon as all *other* Write processes have close the same Fifo.