# Linux named pipes: not as FIFO as thought

Tags: linux, fifo

In short:

```
mkfifo fifo; (echo a > fifo) &; (echo b > fifo) &; cat fifo
```

What I expected:

```
a
b
```

since the first `echo … > fifo` should be the first to have opened the file, so I expect that process to be the first to write to it (with its open unblocking first).

What I get:

```
b
a
```

To my surprise, this behaviour also happened when opening two separate terminals to do the writing in definitely independent processes.

Am I misunderstanding something about the first-in, first-out semantics of a named pipe?

Stephen suggested adding a delay:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/zsh
delay=$1
N=$(( $2 - 1 ))
out=$(for n in {00..$N}; do
  mkfifo /tmp/fifo$n
  (echo $n > /tmp/fifo$n) &
  sleep $delay
  (echo $(( $n + 1000 )) > /tmp/fifo$n )&
  # intentionally using `cat` here to not step into any smartness
  cat /tmp/fifo$n | sort -C || echo +1
  rm /tmp/fifo$n
done)
echo "$(( $res )) inverted out of $(( $N + 1 ))"
```

Now, this works 100% correct (`delay = 0.1, N = 100`).

Still, running `mkfifo fifo; (echo a > fifo) &; sleep 0.1 ; (echo b > fifo) &; cat fifo` manually *almost always* yields the inverted order.

In fact, even copying and pasting the `for` loop itself fails about half of the time. I'm **very** confused about what's happening here.

Comment: Your last test *isn’t* the same as mine, because your `sleep` delays `cat` as well as `echo`. I’m only delaying `echo`.

Comment: Ah I see that point, but yeah, if your test would not be fixing things, hell would break loose, that's for sure.

Comment: Another problem (which isn't apparent in this simple example) is that the writes are not atomic. `a\nb\n` and `b\na\n` are the two results you *expect* to see, but `ab\n\n` and `ba\n\n` may also possible, if one writer interrupts the other mid-write. You need to synchronize writes to the same pipe (which in shell means using something like `flock`).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This has nothing to do with FIFO semantics of pipes, and doesn’t prove anything about them either way. It has to do with the fact that FIFOs block on opening until they are opened for both writing and reading; so nothing happens until `cat` opens `fifo` for reading.

> since the first `echo` should be first.

Starting processes in the background means that you don’t know when they will actually be scheduled, so there’s **no guarantee** that the first background process will do its work before the second one. The same applies to **unblocking blocked processes**.

You can improve the odds, while still using background processes, by artificially delaying the second one:

```
rm fifo; mkfifo fifo; echo a > fifo & (sleep 0.1; echo b > fifo) & cat fifo
```

The longer the delay, the better the odds: `echo a > fifo` blocks waiting to finish opening `fifo`, `cat` starts and opens `fifo` which unblocks `echo a`, and then `echo b` runs.

However the major factor here is when `cat` opens the FIFO: until then, the shells block trying to set up the redirections. The output order seen ultimately depends on the order in which the writing processes are unblocked.

You’ll get different results if you run `cat` first:

```
rm fifo; mkfifo fifo; cat fifo & echo a > fifo & echo b > fifo
```

That way, opening `fifo` for writing will tend not to block (still, without guarantees), so you’ll see `a` first with a higher frequency than in the first setup. You’ll also see `cat` finishing before `echo b` runs, *i.e.* only `a` being output.

Comment: Hi! I think your answer writing and my clarifying edit had (ironically) concurrent behaviour; I specified: *since the first echo … > fifo should be the first to have opened the file, so I expect that process to be the first to write to it (with its open unblocking first).* However, I can **not** confirm that delays increase the likelihood of things being in order. In fact, I took seconds to type "echo b> fifo" in that new terminal that I opened for just that purpose, and it reliably comes out with the b first. Let me write a test case...

Comment: great, the moment I paste the same code into a text file and run it as script, it works reliably...

Comment: so the point is that I wonder about the randomness of the unblocking of `openat`, I guess

Comment: The randomness of unblocking is the randomness of scheduling in the end...

Comment: (I'm currently learning interesting new things, were you aware of the `O_DIRECT` flag to `pipe2`? Cool!)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, all of that is possible.

Comment: Anyway, I think you've really answered what I was asking, so I've accepted. Let me highlight the core statement.

Comment: right, of course it doesn't help to just have `cat &` first, we'd need to wait for it to actually open the fifo... `exec 9<fifo` first and then `cat <&9` at the end? Or just doing it from a C program where you can just `open()` the fifo... Not that it's too easy to see if the `echo`s end up blocking on the open anyway, since the delay's going to be short.

Comment: @ilkkachu I might be missing half of your statement here?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I mean that doing `cat & echo & echo &` isn't much different from `echo & echo & cat &` since even if listed first, the `cat` may end up getting scheduled later, and the `echo`s may block on opening the pipe anyway. But just for a short moment, so it's hard to detect. (Well, in `echo > fifo` it's the child shell handling the redirection that opens the pipe, but anyway.) If we had `exec 9<fifo; echo & echo &`, we'd know the pipe was open for reading before the shell went on to fork off the background jobs.

Comment: But yeah, it's the simultaneous scheduling of background processes that's the main thing, not the blocking on the pipe open as much.

Comment: You can see the blocks by running `strace -f sh -c "..."`.

Comment: @ilkkachu: On an idle modern desktop/laptop, an 0.1 second sleep is plenty of time for a background echo or cat to get to their system call.  That will rarely take even double-digit milliseconds.  So `cat fifo & sleep 0.1; echo a > fifo &;` etc.  (sleep after forking off a `cat`, before starting background processes that write into the fifo).  But yeah without the sleep, it's quite possible for the processes that will do an echo builtin to win the race and block on opening as they're setting up redirects.

Answer (score 33):

Pipes are first-in first-out. Your problem is that you misunderstand when the “in” happens. The “in” event is *writing*, not opening.

Removing useless punctuation, your code is:

```
echo a > fifo & echo b > fifo &
```

This runs the commands `echo a > fifo` and `echo b > fifo` in parallel. Whatever gets in first will get out first, but it's a roughly equal race as to which one gets in first.

If you want `a` to be read before `b`, you have to arrange to write it before `b`. This means you have to wait until `echo a > fifo` is done before you start `echo b > fifo`.

```
{ echo a > fifo; echo b > fifo; } & cat fifo
```

If you want to dig further, you need to distinguish between the elementary operations that happen under the hood. `echo a > fifo` combines three operations:

1. Open `fifo` for writing.
2. Write two characters (`a` and a newline) to the file.
3. Close the file.

You can arrange for these operations to happen at different times:

```
(
    exec >fifo     # 1. open
    sleep 1
    echo a         # 2. write
    sleep 1
)                  # 3. close
```

Likewise, `cat foo` combines an open, a read and a close operation. You can separate them:

```
(
    exec <fifo     # 1. open
    sleep 1
    read line      # 2. read
    echo $line
    sleep 1
)                  # 3. close
```

(The `read` shell builtin might actually make multiple `read` system calls, but that's not important right now.)

Fifos are actually not quite pipes. They're more like potential pipes. The fifo is a directory entry, and a pipe object is created when a process opens the fifo for reading. If a process opens the fifo for writing while no pipe exists, the `open` call blocks until a pipe is created. Furthermore, if a process opens the fifo for reading, this operation also blocks until a process opens the fifo for writing (unless the reader opens the pipe in non-blocking mode, which is not convenient from the shell). As a consequence, the first open-for-reading and the first open-for-writing on a named pipe will return at the same time.

Here's a shell script that puts this knowledge in action.

```
#!/bin/sh
tick () { sleep 0.1; echo tick; echo 0.1; }
mkfifo fifo
{
    exec <fifo; echo >&2 opened for reading;
    echo a; echo >&2 wrote a
} & writer=$!
tick
{
    exec >fifo; echo >&2 opened for writing;
    exec cat >&2;
} & reader=$!
wait $writer
kill $reader
rm fifo
```

Note how both openings happen at the same time (as near as we can observe). And the write can only happen after that.

Note: there is actually a race condition in the script above — but it's not related to the pipes. The `echo >&2` commands are racing against `cat >&2` to write to the terminal, and so you might see `a` from `cat` before `opening for writing` and `wrote a`. If you want to have a more precise view of the timing, you can trace the system calls. For example, under Linux:

```
mkfifo fifo
strace -f -P fifo sh -c '…'
```

Now if you put two writers, both writers will block at the opening step until the reader arrives. It doesn't matter who starts the `open` call first: pipes are first-in-first-out for data, not for open attempts. Whoever *writes* first is what matters. Here's a script to experiment with this.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo fifo
{
    exec >fifo; echo >&2 opened for writing a
    sleep $1
    echo a; echo >&2 wrote a
} & writer_a=$!
{
    exec >fifo; echo >&2 opened for writing b
    sleep $2
    echo b; echo >&2 wrote b
} & writer_b=$!
sleep 0.2
cat fifo & reader=$!
wait $writer_a
wait $writer_b
kill $reader
rm fifo
```

Call the script with two arguments: the wait time for reader a and the wait time for writer b. The reader comes online after 0.2 seconds. If both wait times are less than 0.2 seconds, both writers will try to write as soon as the writers come online, and it's a race. On the other hand, if the wait times are more than 0.2, whoever comes first gets output first.

```
$ ./c 0.1 0.1
# Order of "opened for writing": random
# Order of "a"/"b": random
# Order of "wrote": random, might not match a/b due to echo racing against each other
$ ./c 0.3 0.4
# Order of "opened for writing": random
# Order of "wrote": a then b
# Order of "a"/"b": a then b
```

Comment: Hm, yes, This is an excellent! explanation. Wish I could do more than upvoteright now. The explanations being very illustrative, and the core info leads this whole thing: *Your problem is that you misunderstand when the “in” happens. The “in” event is writing, not opening.*

Comment: Excellent answer, and I love this clear explanation: "_Fifos are actually not quite pipes. They're more like potential pipes._"